# Is there a way that I must approve/reject a user when they sign up? Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using Node.js/express/mongodb/etc - And I have a question. Is it possible when a new member signs up, I receive a notification, either by email or on the dashboard, asking if I want to approve or reject them joining my site?

Comment: Yes you can.But its way too subjective .You could follow a event driven architecture or may be a mom model ,or simply register user and ask them to wait for approval and with your dashboard make the `isapproved` entry to true in your collection or table (depending on your db) .For better answer put some code.Thanks

Comment: Thank you Shubh! that was really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very possible, but try breaking this down in smaller steps. For example, learn how to make an admin `dashboard` page with express, and learn how to send mail using `nodemailer`.

Then, add links to the "accept" or "reject" (depending on your format) that trigger those actions with a little bit of authentication. I recommend that if your hosting it locally have the dashboard locally; otherwise, try to add remote security.

Comment: Thank you Leo! I really appreciate you taking the time to respond and the above is super helpful!!